# Is there any Python based network simulator which can be use to design protocols?

Tags: python, networking

For my academic project I have to build [AODV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_On-Demand_Distance_Vector_Routing) protocol and implement security algorithm on the data using simulator.

Example for simulators: Cooja, NS3 etc.

But we have to use C or C++ in it. I want to use Python in my project. **Is there any simulator available which allow me to use Python in it to build [AODV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_On-Demand_Distance_Vector_Routing) protocol?**